# What is preventing me from using the array of objects I created?

Tags: java

I have a working class called Song that consists of two strings, a song title and the name of the artist of the song.  I am able to create a "TopTen" object, but whenever I try to use the name of the array "arr" in the TopTen class, I get an error.  If anyone could explain why I am getting an error for this simple of a problem, it would be very much appreciated.

```
public class TopTen {

    private Song[] arr;


    public TopTen()
    {
        Song[] arr = new Song[10];
    }

    public int findLength()
    {
        int length = arr.length;
        return length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's scope is not dynamic, so any variables defined within methods (or constructors) are local to that method (or constructor).  You're not actually initializing the array you defined beneath your class' definition:

```
public TopTen()
{
    Song[] arr = new Song[10];
}
```

Should be:

```
public TopTen() {
    arr = new Song[10];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`public TopTen()
{
   Song[] arr = new Song[10];
}`

Here, arr variable is local to the constructor TopTen, make arr = new Song[10];